# price remove via preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, price

I m trying to remove price from string via **preg_replace with regular expression** but it is not working. i want to remove 202,00 from given string

```
<?php
   $haystack = "4 x 3XS - € 202,00, L, 2XS, 4 x XS - € 202,00, S";
   echo preg_replace('/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\,\d{2})?$/','',$haystack);
?>
```

Expected result:

**4 x 3XS, L, 2XS, 4 x XS, S**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i edited the question please check expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$haystack = "4 x 3XS - € 202,00, L, 2XS, 4 x XS - € 202,00, S";
echo preg_replace('/\s*(?:-\s*)?€\s*\d+(?:,\d+)?/u','',$haystack);
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/gr0yVp)

Since the pattern contains Unicode char, it is safer to add `u` modifier to the regex. The pattern matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:-\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and 0+ whitespaces
- `€` -  a euro symbol
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 1+ digits.

Comment: Awesome. Working perfectly. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression:

```
(?<=€\s)(\d*,?\d+)
```

- `(?<=€\s)` Lookbehind for `€` symbol and whitespace.
- `(\d*,?\d+)` Capture digits, comma optionally, digits.

Your code becomes:

```
 <?php
   $haystack = "4 x 3XS - € 202,00, L, 2XS, 4 x XS - € 202,00, S";
   echo preg_replace('/(?<=€\s)(\d*,?\d+)/','',$haystack);
?>
```

*Output*:

`4 x 3XS - €  L, 2XS, 4 x XS - €  S`

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/8wpM5h).

Comment: @NiravJoshi Note that `'/(?<=€\s)(\d+,\d+)/'` won't handle `€ 2` case. `\d+,\d+` will require digits on both ends of `,`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew than how to solve that. Can you please help me?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point, thank you. I've updated my answer Nirav.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yeah, but still there are euro symbols left in the string, OP needs to remove them, too, together with hyphens, if any. At least that is how I interpret the expected output in the question. Actually, I do not understand the purpose of the lookbehind and the capturing group in your pattern, you do not need these constructs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's right, I only just say OP's latest edit. Initially that information was not there. At least thats what I gathered by `i want to remove 202,00`.

Comment: yes sorry, my bad I haven't added the expected result.